# Why are there so many oranges in Sheridan's quarters?

Tags: babylon-5, food

I've noticed that there are a very large number of oranges in Sheridan's quarters for some reason, and I also noticed a few in Garibaldi's (although Zach did ask, are you on a diet? hinting that it might not be ordinary).  It doesn't seem that it was referenced in any special way or explained as I recall.  Why is this?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

John's obsession with oranges seems to stem from his childhood, eating oranges from his family's orchard.

> When I was 12, I used to sit in my dad's garden the air full of the smell of orange blossoms watching the sky, dreaming of faraway places.
>
> <sub><sup>The Geometry of Shadows</sup></sub>

And deprivation of them while he was out on the rim as captain of the Agamemnon.

> I haven't had an orange in almost two years. I used to dream about them. Grapes, nectarines, plums, the black ones, not the red ones. I mean, it's amazing what two years on the Rim can do to you. I have a hunch I'll be spending a lot of time in Hydroponics.
>
> <sub><sup>Points of Departure</sup></sub>

Obviously as captain of the station, one of the perks is access to stocks directly from the hydroponic gardens, including oranges.

Comment: The smell of orange blossoms was an important plot point.  After speaking with Sheridan the leader of the Techno Mages produces an orange blossom for him.  A seeming small miracle to convince Sheridan to let them continue their journey without further interference and the sincerity of their actions.  The orange blossom was an entirely personal object with deep meaning only to Sheridan.

Comment: The famous "oranges" link is as a predictor of death, in the Godfather movies.  Are there any other similar callbacks ?